# What is the difference between git "set-upstream-to" and "track" options

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch, git-remote

Recently, I tried to set my local branch `feature` to track changes on my remote branch like this:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream feature origin/feature
```

Everything went well, but I got that message saying:

```
The --set-upstream flag is deprecated and will be removed. Consider using --track or --set-upstream-to
```

My question is how to use the `track` and `set-upstream-to` options and if there is a significant difference between them.

**UPDATE:** I'm using `git` version `1.8.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git a branch that tracks (or has an upstream) has the an entry similar to the following in the repository config file (/.git/config)

```
[branch "feature"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/feature
```

The "--set-upstream" option you have been using has been directly replaced with "--track"

so

```
git branch --track feature origin/feature
```

additionally there is a new syntax like

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature feature
```

and also

```
git branch -u origin/feature feature
```

All forms function identically.

Answer (score 2):

The `--track` flag is meant to be used when creating a new branch:

```
git branch --no-track foo origin/master  # new local foo, with no upstream
git branch --track bar origin/master     # new local bar, tracks origin/master
```

In both of these cases, you tell git that the new local branch is to be created with it currently pointing to the commit identified by the second argument (`origin/master` here).  The branch then also either does not, or does, "track" the other branch (which just means that `git status` will say things like `ahead 2, behind 1`, and `git pull` will know what to merge-with).

If you specify neither of these options, `git branch` guesses whether to track or not based whether you give it a second argument (but see also the `branch.autosetupmerge` configuration flag).  (This is slightly different from `git checkout` with a branch name that does not exist; this looks for a remote-tracking branch with a "similar enough" name).

The old `--set-upstream` and the new `--set-upstream-to` are identical *except* for argument order/placement.  The issue being fixed is that to change `foo` to track `origin/master` after all, you had to write:

```
git branch --set-upstream foo origin/master
```

which "looks like" you're asking to set `origin/master` to have `foo` as its upstream.  With:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master foo
```

it's clear that you're setting `foo` to have `origin/master` as its upstream.  Moreover, this allows you to set the *current* branch's upstream without having to write the *name* of the current branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

which is much more like the remaining `git branch` commands (they all default to working on the current branch).

Note that both the old `set-upstream` and the new `set-upstream-to` are used after the branch already exists.  (Also, it's hard to type these answers with a cat walking over lap and keyboard :-) )

Comment: nice answer and be patient with your cat :)

Comment: Maybe your cat was trying to help you answer the question. :)